# In elastic search aggregate by one field then by two fields using date range

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have entity of this type saved to elasticSearch:

```
class Value {
  
  private Integer priority;
  private Date dueDate;
```

}

For priority possible values are 1 and 2(I know that enum should be used but let's not concentrate on that).
Now using elastic search I want to get the following result:

1. How many values I have with priority 1 that have dueDate today or in the past
2. How many values I have with priority 1 that have dueDate null or in the future
3. How many values I have with priority 2 that have dueDate today or in the past
4. How many values I have with priority 2 that have dueDate null or in the future

What I tried doing is the following:

```
SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest.Builder()
                .index(MY_INDEX)
                .query(getQuery(someKeys))
                .aggregations(ELASTIC_AGG_PRIORITY, Aggregation.of(a ->
                        a.terms(terms -> terms.field(ELASTIC_AGG_PRIORITY).missing(""))))
                .build();
```

This will get me aggregations that are grouped by priority and will know the number of values with priority 1 and with priority 2. But I need to add nested aggregations and here is my issue. How to separate these buckets that I am getting into one with dueDate in past or today and with dueDate in future or null. Additionally I am having issue with writing the range query:

```
public static Query getRangeQuery(String field) {
    return QueryBuilders.range().field(field).lte(JsonData.of(new Date())).build()._toQuery();
}
```

I am not able to pass the year and I don't know how to handle the nulls when I need to select everything in the future and null values. I tried the following but not getting the result I need:

```
SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest.Builder()
                .index(MY_INDEX)
                .query(getQuery(someKeys))
                .aggregations(ELASTIC_AGG_ASSIGNEE, Aggregation.of(a ->
                        a.terms(terms -> terms.field(ELASTIC_AGG_ASSIGNEE).missing(""))))
                .aggregations(ELASTIC_AGG_PRIORITY, Aggregation.of(a ->
                                a.terms(terms -> terms.field(ELASTIC_AGG_PRIORITY).missing(""))
                                        .aggregations(ELASTIC_AGG_PRIORITY, Aggregation.of(filterAgg -> filterAgg
                                                .filter(QueryUtil.getRangeQuery("dueDate"))))
                        )
                ).build();
```

where `QueryUtil.getRangeQuery(` is the method described above.

So to summarise my question is how to get the 4 above mentioned results?

Answer (score 1):

You're close but you need to implement the "date_range_aggregation" to get the results you are looking for.

Your terms aggregation is ok, all you need to do is add the date_range_aggregation as a subaggregation to the terms aggregation.

For your "null" values, set a "missing" value as something in the past.That way you can pick that up as a third bucket.

Sample[in json]:

```
{
   "aggs": {
       "range": {
           "date_range": {
               "field": "date",
               "missing": "1976/11/30",
               "ranges": [
                  { 
                    "key": "Oldest",
                    "to" : "1976/11/30"
                  },
                  {
                    "key": "Past",
                    "from" : "1976/11/30"
                    "to": "now"
                  }, 
                  {
                    "key": "Future",
                    "from": "now"
                  }
              ]
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I managed to get all for the current day and for the past passing new Date().getTime() and all of the rest will be either null or either in the future. Maybe not the best solution but it works. I honestly don't know how to write this thing in java, I am having issue combining the `terms` and the `filter`